# Discord py How to make the bot leave voice channel after the mp3 file is finished?

Tags: python

Discord py How to make the bot leave voice channel after the mp3 file is finished?

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def ea(ctx):
    if ctx.author.voice:
        channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
        voice = await channel.connect()
        source = FFmpegPCMAudio("./mp3/ea.mp3")
        player = voice.play(source)

    else:
        await ctx.send("")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while voice.is_playing():
     await asyncio.sleep(.1)
await voice.disconnect()
```

This is what I have been using. While Voice is playing it sleeps for a small amount of time. Once whatever is playing is over, it disconnects.

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.VoiceClient